# Why I get wrong answer using pow in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am just using simple `pow()` for calculating the `Int.min`. As we know `Int64.min` is:

```
-9_223_372_036_854_775_808
```

but when I use pow() with this down code, I do get wrong answer! why?

```
let Int64Min = -pow(2.0, 64)/2
```

that gives us this:

```
-9_223_372_036_854_776_000
```

---

For example it works fine for lower numbers like this:

```
let Int8Min = -pow(2.0, 8)/2
```

which gives right Answer and `Int8.min` it is :

```
-128
```

But why does not work for power 64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow` returns a Double. Not every Int64 can be expressed as a Double, so you're seeing the rounding. Every Int8 can be expressed as a Double, so there's no rounding.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong version of `pow`. You need to use the version taking a `Decimal` as `x`, not a `Double`. `Double` cannot represent all Integer numbers and hence you run into rounding errors. On the other hand, `Decimal` is able to represent all integers, so using the `Decimal` version of `pow` you get the correct result.

```
let int64min = -pow(2, 64)/2
print(int64min) // -9_223_372_036_854_775_808
int64min == Decimal(Int64.min) // true
```

Comment: thanks, but I know that! I have to use 2.0 otherwise I cannot convert it to String! I am not just declaring and initializing **int64min** for print

Comment: @Omid that doesn't make sense. Why would you need a `Double` for `String` conversion? You can just do it using `"\(int64min)"` or `int64min.description`.